# Server side method not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

From the below javascript code i am trying to call a serverside method, but serververside method is not getting called. I am using jquery, ajax

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="JquryLib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function fnPopulateCities() {
        debugger;
        var State = $("#ddlState").val();
        GetCities(State);
        return false;
    }
    function GetCities(StateId) {
        debugger;
        var v1 = 'StateId: ' + StateId;
        $.ajax(
     {
         type: "POST",
         url: 'DropDownList_Cascade.aspx/PopulateCities',
         data: '{' + v1 + '}',
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (result) {
             if (result.status === "OK") {
                 alert('Success!!');
             }
             else {
                 fnDisplayCities(result);
             }
         },
         error: function (req, status, error) {
             alert("Sorry! Not able to retrieve cities");
         }
     });
 }
</script>
```

This is my serverside method which i need to call.

```cs
private static ArrayList PopulateCities(int StateId)
{
    //this code returns Cities ArrayList from database.
}
```

It is giving me the following error: 500 (Internal Server Error)

I cannot figure out what is wrong. please help!

**Stack Trace:**

[ArgumentException: Unknown web method PopulateCities.Parameter name: methodName]

Comment: Do you have the `WebMethod` attribute set? And doesn't the method need to be `public`?

Comment: var v1 = "StateId: '" + "'" + StateId + "'";

Comment: The error is happening somewhere on the server-side, though it could possibly be caused by the invalid json you are sending to it.

Comment: how silly of me. sorry i din't have the access modifier set to `public` and thats why the method was not getting called. Thank you very much guys! and yes i had `WebMethod` attribute set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this script:

```
function fnPopulateCities() {
            debugger;
            var State = $("#ddlState").val();
            GetCities(State);
            return false;
        }
        function GetCities(StateId) {
            debugger;

            var data = {
                'StateId': StateId
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'DropDownList_Cascade.aspx/PopulateCities',
                data: JSON.stringify(data), // using from JSON.stringify is much better than to try stringify data manually
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.status === "OK") {
                        alert('Success!!');
                    }
                    else {
                        fnDisplayCities(result);
                    }
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    alert("Sorry! Not able to retrieve cities");
                }
            });
        }
```

and this code for your code behind:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static ArrayList PopulateCities(int StateId)
    {
        //this code returns Cities ArrayList from database.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this script

```
function GetCities(StateId) {
        debugger;
        var v1 = "{'StateId': '" + StateId+"'}";
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'DropDownList_Cascade.aspx/PopulateCities',
         data: v1,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (result) {
             if (result.status === "OK") {
                 alert('Success!!');
             }
             else {
                 fnDisplayCities(result);
             }
         },
         error: function (req, status, error) {
             alert("Sorry! Not able to retrieve cities");
         }
     });
 }
```

and modify Code Behind

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static ArrayList PopulateCities(int StateId)
{
    //this code returns Cities ArrayList from database.
}
```